Small 12v relay for motor
I wanted to make an automated motor driver with a relay module. Can I use this given relay to switch my motor. The motor is a 1/2 HP single phase centrifugal pump (240v 50hz AC). Is this given relay adequate for the job or should I use a bigger specification?
The print shows 1/2HP at 240V AC.


Yes, the relay is adequately rated to control a 240 V ~ 50 Hz 0.5 HP motor.
Here's the datasheet.

Thank you. I'll buy them as a module with a optocoupler included.

Anytime, Kokachi!
